# jenkins Multibranch pipeline plan runs with bitbucket merge event

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run jenkin plan branch from bitbucket merge event.I have configure the jenkin plan branch source behaviours to discover merging pull request and identified when the time i have save that configs the plan get activated. Then the second code merge happen plan will not invoke.

Jenkin can not identify branch indexing for Multibranch pipeline plans.Can some one help me with this issue.I do not need to config webhooks from bitbucket server.